# Lightbox function works part of the time

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I Have an word that when clicked it brings up an image of that word in the lightbox... when you click another image it changes the words displayed in that div to another group of words. on first load the lightbox works but as soon as you change out the words the lightbox doesnt work and it loads a separate page with the picture in it.

```
$(function() {
$('#thmb1').click(function() {
var bigImg = document.getElementById("bigImg");
var desc = document.getElementById("Descriptors");
bigImg.innerHTML='<img src="./images/Slider/Placeholder_1.jpg" alt="Helix Jerseys"/>'
desc.innerHTML='<a href="./images/slimming_lines.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Descriptor 1</a><a href="./images/slimming_lines.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Descriptor 2</a><a href="./images/slimming_lines.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Descriptor 3</a>'
});

$('#thmb2').click(function() {
var bigImg = document.getElementById("bigImg");
var desc = document.getElementById("Descriptors");
bigImg.innerHTML='<img src="./images/Slider/Placeholder_2.jpg" alt="Helix Jerseys"/>'
desc.innerHTML='<a href="./images/slimming_lines.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Descriptor 4</a><a href="./images/slimming_lines.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Descriptor 5</a><a href="./images/slimming_lines.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Descriptor 6</a>'
});

});

 <div id="LeftSliders">
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <h2>Sub Title</h2>
            <div id="smallImg">
            <img src="./images/Slider/Placeholder_1thmb.jpg" alt="Helix Jerseys" id="thmb1"/>
            <img src="./images/Slider/Placeholder_2thmb.jpg" alt="Helix Jerseys" id="thmb2"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="bigImg">
            <img src="./images/Slider/Placeholder_1.jpg" alt="Helix Jerseys"/>
        </div>
        <div id="Descriptors">
            <a href="./images/slimming_lines.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Descriptor 1">Descriptor 1</a><a href="./images/slimming_lines.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Descriptor 2">Descriptor 2</a><a href="./images/slimming_lines.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Descriptor 3">Descriptor 3</a>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: when the click function happens do i need to somehow reload the JS or reset something?

Comment: or is there a more clean way to do an image swap and set of links swap that wouldn't make it so I have this issue.